# jQuery change <i> image on hover menu <li> items

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover

on [my site](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl) in the main menu (drop down) i have some links divided in columns. The menu is controlled via the Magento admin. I can't do anything about the HTML structure. But i can add CSS class to the `<li>` element, and i can attach images to the `<li>` in the `<i>` attribute.

I want to swap/change the main image (in the third column) when you hover a menu item.

This is the structure of a certain `<li>` element (menu item):

```
<li class="imageLink ">
  <a title="Babyboek" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/babyboek.html" target="_self">
    <i class="">
      <img src="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/media//menupro/Image-1415003994.png">
    </i>
    <‌​span>Babyboek</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Is it possible to do it with jQuery? And what is the best solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried?

Comment: please show us the code, what it lookis like without manipulating and how it should look like after manipulating :)

Comment: with "the third collum" you mean what exactly? .. out of the `i`, dirent into the `a`?

Comment: Google: element:hover css

Comment: you are using `$(this).data('thumb')` where or when're you adding thumb data to the `li.imgLink` element

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<li class="imageLink" data-thumb="http://placehold.it/70x70/456.png">
     <a title="Collegaboek" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/collegaboek.html" target="_self">
      <i>
       <img style="display:none" src="http://placehold.it/120/00ff55.png" />
      </i>
       <span>Collegaboek</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

Below is **script** and here is the **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/1Ltjsz8r/)**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("mouseover",".imageLink",function () {
            var imgSrc = $('img', this).attr('src');

            $(this).closest(".parent")
                    .find(".imageChangeDefault")
                    .html(imgSrc ? $('<img />', { src: imgSrc }) : '');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: i can't because of the plugin. I have to stay with my HTML structure.. Isn't there a solution for the `<i>` attribute: `<i class="">
      <img src="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/media//menupro/Image-1415003994.png">
    </i>` thanks!

Comment: Thanks! but do you know why its not working on [my site](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl) ?